# Execute command/handler of an existing plugin from a different plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have an RCP application with an existing command and handler to switch perspective programmatically. And I also have and new plugin consumed by the existing RCP application. I want this new plugin to execute the command/handler of my RCP application, what can be the possible solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need to define a handler for that command (not sure), but executing commands programmatically looks like this:

```java
Command command = ((ICommandService) getSite().getService(ICommandService.class)).getCommand(commandId);
...
final Event trigger = new Event();
ExecutionEvent executionEvent = ((IHandlerService) getSite().getService(IHandlerService.class)).createExecutionEvent(command, trigger);
command.executeWithChecks(executionEvent);
```

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to execute a command. @Bela presented one - I usually use the following code:

```java
ICommandService commandService = (ICommandService) locationService.getService(ICommandService.class);
IHandlerService hs = (IHandlerService) locationService.getService(IHandlerService.class);

ParameterizedCommand pc = commandService.deserialize("<cmd-id>(<p-id>=<value>)");

hs.executeCommand(pc, null);
```

The advantage of this method is primary that it allows you to add parameters to a command - e.g. the `newWizardId` of the `org.eclipse.ui.newWizard`.