# What is the API for Show in System Explorer in Eclipse Platform

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

I want to know whether there is any platform independent Eclipse platform API as part of `IResource` to open the folder or directory in Explorer. As part of eclipse plugin development, I  know that it can be developed specific to OS like Windows, Mac or Linux. But I am interested to know any such functionality of Eclipse platform. Eclipse also provides such functionality as part of IDE to **Show in System Explorer**. You can see the following image. Basically I am interested to know about any such `IResource` API. In windows we can execute the command from command prompt to open the folder in explorer using `explorer.exe .` Please suggest me. I have also gone through the following SO links.

[Eclipse show project in explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11514509/eclipse-show-project-in-explorer)

[In eclipse, reveal current file in filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161240/in-eclipse-reveal-current-file-in-filesystem)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code that the Resource Info page uses:

```java
ECommandService commandService = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(ECommandService.class);
EHandlerService handlerService = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(EHandlerService.class);

Command command = commandService.getCommand(ShowInSystemExplorerHandler.ID);
if (command.isDefined()) {
    ParameterizedCommand parameterizedCommand = commandService
        .createCommand(ShowInSystemExplorerHandler.ID, Collections.singletonMap(
                        ShowInSystemExplorerHandler.RESOURCE_PATH_PARAMETER, locationStr));
    if (handlerService.canExecute(parameterizedCommand)) {
        handlerService.executeHandler(parameterizedCommand);
    }
}
```

where `locationStr` is the full path of the resource.

Note the `ShowInSystemExplorerHandler` class is internal so accessing the static fields is really against the rules, but should be OK here or you can just copy the strings to your own constants.

Comment: Superb, Sir I was expecting the answer from you.

Comment: Sir, I have posted a similar question, please help me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62865684/unable-to-open-multiple-selected-files-and-folders-using-eclipse-showinsystemexp

Answer (score 3):

You could [call](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCommandsAdvanced/article.html#calling-commands-directly-via-code) the *Show in System Explorer* **command** which has the ID [**`org.eclipse.ui.ide.showInSystemExplorer`**](https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.ui.ide/plugin.xml?id=0f720a7a91752c8acb93855af5665b6081e895ed#n1062) for that.

Comment: Thanks for providing information, how can I pass folder or file path in the api? Let us say I have `IFile` or `IFolder`, I want to pass it in the api method. Besides, I am not usine eclipse e4, it is a traditional plugin. Please suggest me. By the way, for the information +1 from my side.

Comment: @Sambit That's not e4 specific. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9666818/6505250) and [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform_Command_Framework#Executing_a_command_with_parameters).