# Unable to open multiple selected files and folders using Eclipse ShowInSystemExplorerHandler API

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

Hi I am using Eclipse `ShowInSystemExplorerHandler` API, it is working fine if I select a single file or folder. But it does not work for multiple selection of files or folders. I provide below the code snippet. Please help me how to resolve so that I should be able to open multiple folders/files in OS specific explorer. By the way I am using `structuredSelection.forEach` so that I can open all the files and folders.

Find below the code.

```java
@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
public class OpenExplorerHandler extends AbstractHandler {
    
    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
        IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindowChecked(event);
        ISelectionService service = window.getSelectionService();
        IStructuredSelection structuredSelection = (IStructuredSelection) service.getSelection();

        structuredSelection.forEach( selctionElement -> {
            if (selctionElement instanceof IAdaptable) {
                IResource resource = (IResource) ((IAdaptable) selctionElement).getAdapter(IResource.class);
                File selectedFileFolder = resource.getLocation().toFile();
                String filePath = selectedFileFolder.getAbsolutePath();
                
                ECommandService commandService = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(ECommandService.class);
                EHandlerService handlerService = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(EHandlerService.class);
                Command command = commandService.getCommand(ShowInSystemExplorerHandler.ID);
                
                if (command.isDefined()) {
                    ParameterizedCommand parameterizedCommand = commandService
                        .createCommand(ShowInSystemExplorerHandler.ID, Collections.singletonMap(
                                        ShowInSystemExplorerHandler.RESOURCE_PATH_PARAMETER, filePath));
                    if (handlerService.canExecute(parameterizedCommand)) {
                        handlerService.executeHandler(parameterizedCommand);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well what is happening? I would think this would open multiple explorer windows. The ShowInSystemExplorerHandler command handler only supports opening a single path.

Comment: Sir, If I select a single  file or folder, it works. But If I make multiple selection of file or folder, it does not open. By the way I am iterating using `structuredSelection.forEach( selctionElement -> {  ...}` and trying to open the folders.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of the `ShowInSystemExplorerHandler` command handler turns out to be rather odd. Although you can pass the resource to open as a parameter (which you are doing) it still looks at the number of items currently selected to determine if the handler is enabled and will only be enabled when exactly one item is selected.

If you debug the code you will see that `handlerService.canExecute(parameterizedCommand)` is returning false because more that one item is selected.

So it doesn't look like you can use this directly with multiple items selected.

What you can do is define your own command and handler that calls the same code. Something like:

```xml
   <extension
      point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
   <command
         categoryId="org.eclipse.ui.category.navigate"
         name="show in explorer"
         id="my.showInSystemExplorer"
         description="Show in Explorer">
      <commandParameter
            id="org.eclipse.ui.ide.showInSystemExplorer.path"
            name="Resource path"
            optional="false">
      </commandParameter>
   </command>
</extension>
```

```xml
 <extension
      point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
   <handler
         class="org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.handlers.ShowInSystemExplorerHandler"
         commandId="my.showInSystemExplorer">
    </handler>
 </extension>
```

Then replace `ShowInSystemExplorerHandler.ID` in the code with the id of your command (`my.showInSystemExplorer` in the example).

Comment: Yes, I have already see it. Sir, is there any way I can activate the handler every time so that it will execute it?

Comment: You would have to arrange that there is only one item selected each time the handler is called.

Comment: I have added a workaround using a different command and handler calling the same code

Comment: Let me try Sir, I will come back to you.

Comment: Sir, I tried, it opens only one folder even if I select multiple folders in a project.